# How can I use UIBarButtonSystemItem icons for UITabBar ButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonsystemitem

It looks like the `systemItem` property doesn't exist on the `viewController.tabBarItem` is there a way to set `UIBarButtonSystemItem` as an image for a `UITabBarItem` programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `UIBarButtonSystemItem` icons with a `UITabBarItem`. Instead, use `UITabBarSystemItem` icons.

```
let barItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .bookmarks, tag: 1) // or whatever item you want
```